# Как скрыть div в Joomla с jQuery, если пользователь авторизирован?

Tags: php, jquery, joomla, авторизация

Требуется скрыть блок с пользовательской инфо, если он авторизирован на сайте. Написал этот код, но он не срабатывает. в чем может быть ошибка?

```
<?php 
$user = JFactory::getUser();
if($user->id>=0) { ?>   
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('.menter6').hide();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Разобрался сам. Нужно убрать: $(document).ready(function(){ и все конечные скобки и ; после hide();

Answer (score 0):

А `if($user->id>=0) {`  где закрывается?

Проверь работу `IF`  в JS скрипт поставь `alert( "Привет" );`

Если отработает, то условие корректно.

И следовательно проблема где-то здесь `.menter6`.

Answer (score -1):

```
if($user->id>=0)
```

для проверки пользователя по `$user->id` не может быть условие `>=`

`$user->id > 0` : пользователь авторизирован.

`$user->id == 0` : пользователь не авторизирован.